# How to create simple player in swift iOS application

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am trying to create a simple iOS app with a player. There is a button and when you click the button it should play the stream. My code is as follows:

```
@IBAction func playVideo(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let url = URL(string: "https://.../index.m3u8")!

    // Create the asset instance and the resouce loader because we will be asked
    // for the license to playback DRM protected asset.
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "FP License Acquire")
    asset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(self, queue: queue)

    // Create the player item and the player to play it back in.
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
    let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

    // Create a new AVPlayerViewController and pass it a reference to the player.
    let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
    controller.player = player

    // Modally present the player and call the player's play() method when complete.
    present(controller, animated: true) {
        player.play()
    }

}
```

However I get the following error message for the line "asset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(self, queue: queue)" Error message is:

```
"Cannot convert value of type 'ViewController' to expected argument type 'AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate?'  Insert ' as! AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate'"
```

When I insert the 'as! AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate', it gives the following run time error:

```
Could not cast value of type 'DRMTest.ViewController' (0x1009ae0c8) to 'AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate' (0x1126ebf00).
```

/I am really new to swift and iOS development. I don't understand the problem and don't know what to do. All I need is a simple AVPlayer

Comment: You need to conform to `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` protocol and implement the required methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view controller should conform `AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate` delegate to resolve the error, so the code should look like,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate {
    @IBAction func playVideo(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let url = URL(string: "https://.../index.m3u8")!

        // Create the asset instance and the resouce loader because we will be asked
        // for the license to playback DRM protected asset.
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: url)
        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "FP License Acquire")
        asset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(self, queue: queue)

        // Create the player item and the player to play it back in.
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

        // Create a new AVPlayerViewController and pass it a reference to the player.
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player

        // Modally present the player and call the player's play() method when complete.
        present(controller, animated: true) {
            player.play()
        }
    }
}
```